# Date string not recognized in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

My JavaScript code is working on on Chrome, IE, and Firefox, but when it gets to safari it doesn't work. I believe I have narrowed down the problem: When creating a 'new Date' in JavaScript, all other browsers recognize my string except safari.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="timeIn" value="1:00 AM"/>
<input id="dateIn" value="1/20/2012"/>
<input id="timeOut" value="2:00 AM"/>
<input id="dateOut" value="1/21/2012"/>
</form>​
```

JavaScript:

```
function calcHours() {
    // Build datetime objects and subtract
    var timeIn = new Date($('#timeIn').val() + $('#dateIn').val());
    if(!isValidDate(timeIn)) return -1;
    var timeOut = new Date($('#timeOut').val() + $('#dateOut').val());
    if(!isValidDate(timeOut)) return -1;
    var hours = (timeOut - timeIn)/(1000*60*60);
    return hours.toFixed(1);
}

function isValidDate(d) {
    console.log(d);
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]" ) {
      // it is a date
      if ( isNaN( d.getTime() ) ) {  // d.valueOf() could also work
        // date is not valid
          console.log("isn't valid");
          return 0;
      }
      else {
        // date is valid
          console.log("is valid");
          return 1;
      }
    }
    else {
      // not a date
        console.log("isn't valid");
        return 0;
    }
}
var hours = calcHours();
console.log("Hours:", hours);​
```

I have made a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mq72k/7/. If you open it up in chrome, it will work fine. If you open it up in Safari, it will say invalid date for the same inputs and not work at all. I have also tried varying the string a bit, adding spaces, different order ect.

Does any one have any ideas how to fix this cross browser compatibility issue?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of your code here, not on an independent site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I'm surprised other browsers parse the string correctly, as the string you give to the date object is `1:00 AM1/20/2012`. Put the date first and add a space in between.

```
var timeIn = new Date($('#dateIn').val() + ' ' + $('#timeIn').val());
var timeOut = new Date($('#dateOut').val() + ' ' + $('#timeOut').val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mq72k/8/

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesnt work, no matter where the spaces are, I have varied the string quite a bit-

Comment: Did you try with date first? Does the fiddle I added also not work on your Safari? `1/20/2012 1:00 AM` works fine on my Safari, but `1:00 AM 1/20/2012` does not.

Comment: Juhana, I thought I tried that string variation out, but maybe I didn't. You are correct, flipping the date and time in my fiddle made it work correctly in safari.

Comment: Is this a sloppy way of doing it? are there better practices out there that I should be adapting?

Comment: @Juhana—the **only** format that [ES5 specifies is ISO8601](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15), the OPs strings are not compliant. There is no reason to believe that all browsers now, or in the future, will support non-standard formats, especially one that is so region-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an external plugin to parse your dates, something like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: @Mootz - It's validating the dates on Safari after the **Date.js** mod. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/8Nx3Y/

Answer (score -1):

Javascript does not parse string dates very well at all, including ISO8601 formats. You must parse the string yourself. You especially should not expect a minor format like month/day/year to be parsed since it is used by a small minority of the global population.

Incidentally, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

#### Edit

To reliably parse m/d/y format:

```
function toDate(ds) {
  var a = ds.split('/');
  return new Date(+a[2], (a[0] - 1), +a[1]);
}
```

The above assumes a correct date string is supplied. To check that it's a valid date at the same time:

```
function toDate(ds) {
  var a = ds.split('/');
  var d = new Date(+a[2], (a[0] - 1), +a[1]);

  if (d.getDate() == a[1] && d.getFullYear() == a[2]) {
    return d;

  } else {
    return NaN; // or some other suitable value like null or undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically run a Date.Parse operation in a try catch loop and see if I get the desired output instead of just making a new date with my string?

Comment: Rob thanks for writing an example for me, I appreciate different approaches.

Comment: Cool, it will work in every browser and UA that supports scripting, with no library support, and does the validation as well. Value for money I think. :-)

Comment: Could you help explain this approach to me? Is it beacuse it doesn't depend on the string and the javascript compiler for that browser?

Comment: Yes. `Date.parse` was completely implementation dependent until ES5, but even then only ISO8601 long form is specified, everything else is still implementation dependent. Manual parse is pretty easy (see above) and overcomes cross-browser issues as it uses basic ECMA-262 features available from the begining. The date validation check is also simple, efficient and effective.